# Evaluate the path integral: $\int_{C(0,1)}\sqrt{z+2}\:dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Evaluate the path integral:
$$\int_{C(0,1)}\sqrt{z+2}\:dz$$

Ive been working on this question for a while and cant seem to answer it so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what's $C(0,1)$ ?

Comment: You  "can't seem to answer it"? Does this mean you already know the answer you must get?

Comment: No, Ive just been trying to answer it for a while without any success @DonAntonio

Comment: Since square root is a multi-valued function the question does not make any sense. Unless it specifies that it is the principle root.

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming $C(0,1)$ the circle centred at $0$ of radius $1$. Then by Cauchy's Theorem, the integral is $0$ because $\sqrt{z+2}$ is holomorphic on a simply connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $C(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

The function
$$
f(z)=\sqrt{z+2},
$$
is analytic in
$$
U=\mathbb C\setminus \{x\in\mathbb R: x\le -2\}.
$$
Also, the closed unit $\overline{D}$ is a subset of $U$, and thus, by virtue of the Cauchy Theorem, 
$$
\int_{C(0,1)}f=0.
$$